# Having trouble decoding retrieved JSON object in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, decoder

I am able to retrieve some JSON from an endpoint but then when I try to decode that JSON into my model object something goes wrong to where the json can't be parsed. I've made sure the properties in my model object matched the json keys, so I dont understand what the issue is. It prints out the catch block every time.

Here is my code to retrieve the json:

```
func getServiceProviders() {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let url = URL(string: "http://exampleendpoint.com/example")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in



 //Here is where I try to decode the json into my model object

            do {
            let jsonContent = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServiceObject.self, from: data!)
            print(jsonContent)
        } catch {
            print("Ooops")
        }


}.resume()
```

Here is my model object:

```
     struct ServiceObject: Decodable {
let serviceproviders: [ServiceProvider]



struct ServiceProvider: Decodable {
let city: String
let coordinates: Location
let name: String
let overallGrade: String
let postalCode: Int
let state: String
let reviewCount: Int
 }

 struct Location: Decodable {
let latitude: Double
let longitude: Double
 }

 }
```

Here is what the json object I retrieve looks like:

```
      {
"serviceproviders": [
    {
    "city" : "Beech Grove",
    "coordinates" :                 {
        "latitude" : "39.715417",
        "longitude" : "-86.095646"
    },
    "name" : "William J Ciriello Plumbing Co Inc",
    "overallGrade" : "A",
    "postalCode" : "46107",
    "state" : "Indiana",
    "reviewCount" : 309
},
            {
    "city" : "Indianapolis",
    "coordinates" :                 {
        "latitude" : "39.922607",
        "longitude" : "-86.0267094"
    },
    "name" : "Roby's Plumbing & Appliance Service",
    "overallGrade" : "B",
    "postalCode" : "46256",
    "state" : "Indiana",
    "reviewCount" : 903
},
```

Comment: Instead of printing "oops", use `print(error)`.

Comment: Rather than completely meaningless `print("Ooops")` do `print(error)`. It tells you immediately what's wrong, for example that the value for `serviceproviders` is an array. And you will get (3) other errors. Alternatively (learn to) read the JSON. It's really easy.

Comment: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "serviceproviders", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You delared a dictionary `ServiceProvider` but the value is an array `[ServiceProvider]`. ***Expected*** is the wrong type, ***found*** is the real type. Change the types accordingly for the other 3 errors. Hint: Everything in double quotes is `String`.

Comment: Thanks Vadian. Is there a quick code fix to change it from array to a dictionary?

Comment: The JSON is clearly array. You have to change the other way round. In my last comment there is the fix, note the brackets.

Comment: Could you demonstrate using the code I've provided? please and thans

Comment: `let serviceproviders: [ServiceProvider]`

Comment: The code has been updated yet im still unable to parse the JSON. Thanks for your insight though

Comment: Yes, as I said you get 3 errors *Expected Number but found String*. You have to change the types accordingly. Read the CodingPath. It tells you where the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution!